# Checking if Element hasClass then prepend and Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, prepend

What I am trying to achieve here is when a user clicks an element it becomes hidden, once this happens I want to prepend inside the containing element another Element to make all these items visible again.

```
var checkIfleft = $('#left .module'),checkIfright = $('#right .module');
   if(checkIfleft.hasClass('hidden')) {
       $('#left').prepend('<span class="resetLeft">Reset Left</span>');
        } else if(checkIfright.hasClass('hidden')) {
          right.prepend('<span class="resetRight">Reset Right</span>');
       }
```

I tried multiple ways, and honestly I believe `.length ==1` would be my best bet, because I only want one element to be prepended. I believe the above JS I have will prepend a new element each time a new item is hidden if it worked.

Other Try:

```
var checkIfleft = $('#left .module').hasClass('hidden'),
    checkIfright = $('#right .module').hasClass('hidden');
   if(checkIfleft.length== 1) {
       $('#left').prepend('<span class="resetLeft">Reset Left</span>');
        } else if(checkIfright.length== 1) {
          right.prepend('<span class="resetRight">Reset Right</span>');
       } 
      else if(checkIfleft.length==0){
          $('.resetLeft').remove()
      } else if (checkIfright.length==0){
         $('.resetRight').remove()
      }
```

Basically if one element inside the container is hidden I want a reset button to appear, if not remove that reset button...

Comment: can you share the html for the panels, and the hidden element

Answer (score 1):

`hasClass()` only works on the first item in the collection so it isn't doing what you want.  It won't tell you if any item has that class.

You can do something like this instead where you count how many hidden items there are and if there are 1 or more and there isn't already a reset button, then you add the reset button.  If there are no hidden items and there is a reset button, you remove it:

```
function checkResetButtons() {

    var resetLeft = $('#left .resetLeft').length === 0;
    var resetRight = $('#left .resetRight').length === 0;
    var leftHidden = $('#left .module .hidden').length !== 0;
    var rightHidden = $('#right .module .hidden').length !== 0;

    if (leftHidden && !resetLeft) {
        // make sure a button is added if needed and not already present
        $('#left').prepend('<span class="resetLeft">Reset Left</span>');
    } else if (!leftHidden) {
        // make sure button is removed if no hidden items
        // if no button exists, this just does nothing
        $('#left .resetLeft').remove();
    }

    if (rightHidden && !resetRight) {
        $('#right').prepend('<span class="resetRight">Reset Right</span>');
    } else if (!rightHidden) {
        $('#right .resetRight').remove();
    }

}

// event handlers for the reset buttons
// uses delegated event handling so it will work even though the reset buttons
// are deleted and recreated
$("#left").on("click", ".resetLeft", function() {
    $("#left .hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#left .resetLeft").remove();
});

$("#right").on("click", ".resetRight", function() {
    $("#right .hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#right .resetRight").remove();
});
```

FYI, if we could change the HTML to use more common classes, the separate code for left and right could be combined into one piece of common code.

Comment: I like this way, it seems to work. Only problem is when clicking on the resetLeft it won't make all the Elements within that #left container visible.?

Comment: @EasyBB - I added two event handlers that will handle the reset buttons.  This assumes that the way you make items visible is by removing the `hidden` class.  If there's a different way, then you will have to modify that portion of the code. You will have to call the `checkResetButtons()` function at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the reset button when hiding the `.module`, if it's not already there :

```
$('#left .module').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
    var parent = $(this).closest('#left');
    if ( ! parent.find('.resetLeft') ) {
       var res = $('<span />', {'class': 'resetLeft', text : 'Reset Left'});
       parent.append(res);
       res.one('click', function() {
           $(this).closest('#left').find('.module').show();
           $(this).remove();
       });
    }
});
```

repeat for right side !

Answer (score 0):

I've recently experimented with using CSS to do some of this stuff and I feel that it works quite well if you're not trying to animate it. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/HBxtA/) where I can hide a module and show the reset button in one go by adding/removing a 'hideLeft' or 'hideRight' class to the common parent of the two modules.

It works by hiding both reset button divs at first. Then it uses `.hideLeft #left { display:none;}` and `.hideLeft #right .resetLeft { display: block; }` to hide the left module and display the reset button when `.hideLeft` has been added to whichever element both elements descend from. I was inspired by modernizr a while back and thought it was a neat alternative way to do things. Let me know what you think, if you find it helpful, and if you have any questions :)